# Send email if character/string detected in PowerShell

Tags: email, powershell

**Problem:**
I need a PowerShell script that checks each file in a folder for a specific character (#), then emails the filename only if the character was found.

**What I have:** I'm still new to loops/testing logic and not sure where it would fit in. My current script successfully checks for the bad character, but emails regardless if something was found or not.

```
$scr = dir \\fileshare\businessfolder\filedrop | Select-String '#'

$FromAddress = "myself@something.com"

$ToAddress = "myself@something.com"

$MessageSubject = "Bad Character Detected"

$SendingServer = "mail.something.com"

$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $FromAddress, $ToAddress, $MessageSubject,$scr

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $SendingServer

$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

This currently outputs in an email:

> \fileshare\businessfolder\filedrop\AD060101.107:3:#N/A
>   \fileshare\businessfolder\filedrop\AD060102.107:3:#N/A
>   \fileshare\businessfolder\filedrop\AD060101.103:14:#N/A

The files I'm scanning through are formatted in this way:

AHMMDDNN.LLL

ADMMDDNN.LLL

The AH/AD indicates if it's the header or detail, the MMDD is month/day, and NN is if it's the first generated file for the day, second generated file, et cetera. LLL is the location number.

**What I really want:**
To take it a step further, I would like to delete the bad file header & detail file and email the extension to the business unit.

The process would be:

1. Scan for '#' in all files in the folder.
2. Delete the ADMMDDNN.LLL and corresponding AHMMDDNN.LLL file. (Example: AD060101.107 had a '#' in it, so delete that and the AH060101.107 file too)
3. Send an email stating "location LLL has been deleted, please recreate file". (Example: "Location 107 has been deleted, please recreate file")

Comment: `$src` would be a matches object, not just a string, so it would contain most of the information you need. Namely the file path as a property. Have you tried to accomplish this part of your question on your own?

Comment: I'm lost in _Example: AD060101.107 had a '#' in it_. Do you mean `#` character (Number Sign) found in `AD060101.107` file _content_?

Comment: Yes, sorry, ### meant 107, or 3 int

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over all matches from the [Select-String](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113388) cmdlet and use a `regex` to create a pattern for the [Remove-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113373) (alias `rm`) cmdlet like `A[D|H]060101.103`:

```
$filesToDelete = Select-String -Path '\\fileshare\businessfolder\filedrop\*' -Pattern '#'

$filesToDelete | ForEach-Object {
        'location {0} has been deleted, please recreate file' -f ($_.Filename -split '\.')[-1]
         $_.Path -replace '(.*\\A).(.*)', '$1[D|H]$2'  | rm -Force -ea 0
    }
```

Note: I omit the E-Mail part but added the message to the `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks! I ran with what you provided and had success in my test environment, however I learned that the fileshare I need to run this against is Unix, and the script won't work, it doesn't even throw an error message. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: No, sorry. You could check whether `$filesToDelete` is not empty.